# Firemonkey equivalent to PHP's password_verify() function

Tags: firemonkey, hashcode

Is there a function in Delphi 11.3 FMX that allows me to verify a password with a hash code generated in PHP using password_hash()? A function which does the same as PHP's password_verify($password, $hash)?

```
$hash = password_hash('thisismyaccesscode', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

// $hash == '$2y$10$21qire0Qwz/gj6HEej3tf.skdiZzeB.rgFdg7qD.5rAhE/AFg.U8q'
```

TBCrypt.CheckPassword only for VCL.

Answer (score 0):

Found for FMX on github: [Example 82-BcryptPassword](https://github.com/FMXExpress/Cross-Platform-Samples)